# C++ how to prevent invoking a method more than one in Compile-time?

Tags: c++, g++, compile-time, error-checking

I have a method and I want to force the user calling it at last one in compile-time. 
Currently I have a correct implementation, But it is useful for runtime execution.

Is there a clean way to checking this problem (just one time calling) in compile-time?

```
static void set_logging_type(LOG_TYPE type)
{
    static bool select_type_done{false};

    if (!select_type_done)
    {
        log_type = type;
        select_type_done = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("logging type is selected before!");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No there is no decent way to check it. However, you can call it from static variable - which reduces the requirement from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a clean way to checking this problem (just one time calling) in compile-time?

No.

Determining how many times (or whether at all) `set_logging_type()` is called is equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and thus undecidable (in general).